# Extract temporary from LLVM callInst

Tags: llvm

From the following example call:

```
call void %4(%class.EtherAppReq* %2, i64 %5)
```

I want to extract the temporary %4 to pass it as an argument of another function. To do this, I need it as Value class object. How could I do it?

```
 Value *target = call->getCalledValue();
 Value *args[] = {point, target};
 Builder.CreateCall(func, args);
```

It caused a segmentation fault because of target.

Answer (score 0):

`CallInst::getCalledValue()` to get a pointer to `%4`.

Comment: `getCalledFunction` will return null for indirect calls, need to use `getCalledValue` instead.

Comment: The second half of your answer no longer applies after the edit: The return type of `getCalledValue` is `Value`, so the `Function` class isn't involved at all.

Comment: So, I do use getCalledValue, and use that return value to place as argument in Builder.createCall
N.B. I edit the main post

Answer (score 0):

What I did is attempt to `getCalledFunction`First, if NULL then `getCalledValue` and `stripPointerCasts`, if still fails then bail out or skip this one